# maven javadoc java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: maven, javadoc, java-6

I am using maven3.0.4 and JDK1.6 But when I try site:run and try to see the java doc I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.javadoc.AnnotationTypeDoc
```

I have seen other question in stack overflow.

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314738/javadoc-annotations-from-third-party-libraries),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853/why-am-i-getting-a-classcastexception-when-generating-javadocs),[three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598324/mvn-javadocjavadoc-failing-on-just-one-of-my-module-project?lq=1)

But I am not clear how to over come this issue, I am new to maven, I am using Eclipse indigo. And I use annotations for all my spring service beans. (The third link says, it is JDK issue and suggest to upgrade to java1.7, which I can't do)  So in my POM file, how do I set the class path(for all my dependency), in javadoc report plugin.

my POM looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.hmil</groupId>
<artifactId>sam</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SAM</name>
<description>Sales And Marketing System</description>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>          
        </plugin>
```

...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853/why-am-i-getting-a-classcastexception-when-generating-javadocs

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314738/javadoc-annotations-from-third-party-libraries